# Can someone please help me do a visual analysis of this advertisement

Tags: symbolism, graphic-styles, technique, advertising

** Not a homework question

I recently stumbled upon a very interesting advertisement by an organization called "World for all" . I was thinking of writing an analytical paper on analyzing the graphical techniques used to convey the figurative and literal message of this advert. What are some points of visual/graphical analysis, that can be considered?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In illustration/painting, the technique is sometimes called "chiaroscuro", where the light source is behind the subject.

Comment: it very much reads like homework to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to making a written analysis of a visual element, the most useful is to think as if we had to describe it by phone to someone who doesn't have access to it.

The most relevant visual points are:

- Photographic image
- Extreme light/shadow contrast
- Figure-ground Gestalt Law
- Double narrative or double reading

It's a poster with a photographic image in a very high light/shadow contrast, where the shadows converge from the limits towards the center until ending in the profiles of a woman, a man and a newborn forming an blank empty space in the central axis that by the figure-ground law generates a double reading of a pet (dog) shape.

---

At conceptual level there are other elements to consider.

The fact that a newborn appears with his/her possible parents wrapping the pet figure gives many readings: protection, envelope, room, maternal uterus, genesis, beginning.

But also, the blank empty shape gives a sense of **absence** bringing a disturbing ambiguity:

- Is it a generated absence (does the pet no longer exist)?
- It's an absence to be covered (the pet must arrive)

This ambiguity makes the message not 100% clear, which leads to read the logo on the bottom to try to interpret its meaning.

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I appreciate the help